# Blinking of quadrant area of monitor

Tags: screen

what the reason it might be ?

https://youtu.be/IsykC8eEm5I

Please, any ideas...

UPDATE:
I can see it from time to time in Google Chrome browser, during watching a videos at youtube site. A horizontal blinking has appeared recently as well (again, from time to time).

Comment: Does this happen on BIOS settings too? It looks like a hardware failure to me.

Comment: @Kaz Wolfe, unfortunately I don't understand what does the 1st question mean... What I noticed additionally is that I saw it in Google Chrome, youtube site + horizontal blinking has appeared recently as well :(